# Top 50 Contacts by Number of Cases Opened

Tags: reporting, dashboard

We are trying to build a report to pull Top 50 contacts by number of cases opened.We have 200,000 contacts in our Salesforce.Is it possible with Standard reports in Salesforce ?

Comment: You could use DLRS to rollup the case count onto Contact and then the report becomes trivial

Comment: You can also do this with a dashboard plus summary report.  The top 50 appear in a dashboard table component.  That said, with 200,000 contacts, the report / dashboard might timeout.  But it is an easy experiment to try.